# newsletter need to confirm disabled but unconfirmed from new account form

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, newsletter

I have the Newsletter need to confirm disabled

[image]

When I subscribe from footer or from a logged account it works, but when I subscribe from the new account form then the subscription status is set to unconfirmed.

By default new customers are disabled, and need to be manually activated from backend, but when I activate the new customer then the newsletter status is set automatically to unsubscribed and an unsubscription email is sent to customer.

[image]

In this image customer with id 916 is not yet activated, and customer with id 917 is activated. So the status from 917 went from unconfirmed to unsubscribed. (both are fake emails).

Why are the new customers unconfirmed despite need to confirm is disabled? Why are they unsubscribed when this customers are activated?

**Edit:** I wanted to be sure that need to confirm is off, so just now I  changed the subscribe function in app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Subscriber.php to this:

```
// $isConfirmNeed   = (Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_CONFIRMATION_FLAG) == 1) ? true : false;
$isConfirmNeed = false;
```

But even with this change the new customers subscribed to the newsletter are unconfirmed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've found a solution.

In **`app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Subscriber.php`** in the **subscribeCustomer** function there is the following code:

```
$status = $customer->getIsSubscribed()
          ? (!is_null($confirmation) ? self::STATUS_UNCONFIRMED : self::STATUS_SUBSCRIBED)
          : self::STATUS_UNSUBSCRIBED;
```

So, confirmation is not null, and **self::STATUS_UNCONFIRMED** is asigned to $status.

I changed it to:

```
$status = $customer->getIsSubscribed() ? 
          self::STATUS_SUBSCRIBED : self::STATUS_UNSUBSCRIBED;
```

And now I avoid the unwanted unconfirmed status.

Maybe it is not the best solution, but it works. Now I will override this function model in code/local with the changes (not a good practice edit core files directly)
I hope it helps somebody in the future after updating in local file.

Comment: You should not edit the core files

Comment: @Vivek this is exactly what I said, it is not a good practice to edit core files, so I overrided it in code/local folder.

Comment: yes, thats what I mean :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code ***Mage_Newsletter_SubscriberController***

Make override the controller SubscriberController.
Replace below code with ***newAction***() function.

```
public function newAction()
    {
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost() && $this->getRequest()->getPost('email')) {
            $session            = Mage::getSingleton('core/session');
            $customerSession    = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
            $email              = (string) $this->getRequest()->getPost('email');

            try {
                if (!Zend_Validate::is($email, 'EmailAddress')) {
                    Mage::throwException($this->__('Please enter a valid email address.'));
                }

                if (Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber::XML_PATH_ALLOW_GUEST_SUBSCRIBE_FLAG) != 1 && 
                    !$customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
                    Mage::throwException($this->__('Sorry, but administrator denied subscription for guests. Please <a href="%s">register</a>.', Mage::helper('customer')->getRegisterUrl()));
                }

                $ownerId = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
                        ->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId())
                        ->loadByEmail($email)
                        ->getId();
                if ($ownerId !== null && $ownerId != $customerSession->getId()) {
                    Mage::throwException($this->__('This email address is already assigned to another user.'));
                }

                $status = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->subscribe($email);

                    $subscriber = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->loadByEmail($email);
                    # change status to "subscribed" and save
                    $subscriber->setStatus(Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber::STATUS_SUBSCRIBED);
                    $subscriber->save();


                if ($status == Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber::STATUS_NOT_ACTIVE) {
                    $session->addSuccess($this->__('Confirmation request has been sent.'));
                }
                else {
                    $session->addSuccess($this->__('Thank you for your subscription.'));
                }
            }
            catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                $session->addException($e, $this->__('There was a problem with the subscription: %s', $e->getMessage()));
            }
            catch (Exception $e) {
                $session->addException($e, $this->__('There was a problem with the subscription.'));
            }
        }
        $this->_redirectReferer();
    }
```

Let me know if works!!